# Loop over a range of numbers to download with wget

Tags: while-loop, sh, wget

How can I download a number of files, using wget, the numbers start at 5000000000 and finishes at 9999999999, I found this line but it freezes,

```
wget example.com/imageId={6000000000..7999999999}.jpg
```

Is there a better way to do it ( and work ) and put it in a SH file so it runs with cron ?

Thanks

Comment: how is that related to `ssh` and `cron`?

Comment: please provide output of this: `sh --version`

Comment: ok forget the cron, but is there a way to use WHILE or FOR to create do this ? I was unable to determine SH version.

Comment: why were you unable to determine the version?

Comment: it said  Illegal option and to solve that I have to change a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the version of shell you're using. Since it doesn't accept `{1..4}` and it doesn't accept `--version` it's most probably not bash.

You can try POSIX compatible loop:

```
i=6000000000
max=7999999999
while [ $i -lt $max ]
do
    wget example.com/imageId=$i.jpg
    true $(( i++ ))
done
```